# Encode binary or ASCII (at least 7000 bytes) into image/barcode?

Tags: encoding

I'm wondering if there's some way to encode data (either binary or ASCII) into a printable image or data pattern that can easily be rescanned again and interpreted back into a file. The problem with QR codes is that they won't handle file sizes of 7-10KB. Any suggestions?

EDIT: One catch: Can't store said data on the server. Security reasons. The data must not exist anywhere except on a printed piece of paper.

Comment: A QR is more or less a 2D version of a 1D barcode. QR codes were probably created because the typical barcode didn't hold enough data in a reasonable amount of space. For a barcode to have 7k bytes, it would have to be VERY long and would take one impressive scanner to read. What is your application for needing 7k bytes?

Comment: The maximum you can store in a Version 40 QR code is 2,953 Bytes (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Storage) You might want to look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_barcode#Matrix_.282D.29_barcodes if you can find one with a higher capacity. But what you need this kind of capacity for makes me curious also :-)

Comment: Can't say. Secret project. :)

Answer (score 0):

7 kilobytes is 57344 bits, hence the graphical code needs a lot of bars or squares (in case of QR) in order to represent the data, and that's without thinking of data error correction, format information, positioning, alignment etc...

I think a sound solution will be to put the data on a server. map it with index and create a service to retrieve the data by index.

the QR/barcode will scan index and get the data from the service

Comment: Can't store on the server. Security reasons. The data must not exist anywhere except on a printed piece of paper.

Comment: In that case you can use more than one QR code with maximum capacity and concatenate the data after reading them all

Comment: Or use a bigger, QR-ish code. Use the basic idea with a bigger image, hence more blocks. If you're only using it in a proprietary application, you don't *have* to follow the standards. You'll have to code it yourself, but other than that...

Comment: @Geobits For my humble opinion the bigger the image to recognize, the bigger the false positive&false negative recognition, also the lens can help with deform the original code. I'll consult experts before I try to re-implement the QR algorithm.
If I decide to re implement it I'll use colors to represent more data over a singel spot i.e. 8 different colors can replace 3 dots space in a single dot space.

Comment: Oh, I agree with you. I was just pointing out that standards only *need* to be followed if you're making something for public release. The color idea is a good one, by the way.